# Real Time Object Tracking using image processing

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

How we can track a single selected object from multiple detected moving objects using single fixed camara?

Comment: Question is way too vague - there are entire textbooks dedicated to this and similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of an object?  If it is a compact object moving in some predictable fashion, you can use the Kalman filter to track based on its motion.  If the object has some texture, and doesn't move very fast relative to the frame rate, you can use the KLT (Kanade, Lucas, Tomasi) algorithm to track points on it.  If it has a distinctive color pattern you can use a Mean-shift tracker to track it.

Comment: there are multiple objects in video. objects are people, group of people, birds and vehicles. from that all are detected but we want only selected one to be track. there is single fixed camera and outdoor environment.

Comment: how can we store the information of object and update it next frame to get the knowledge about object? so that can be easy to track that object.

Comment: If the object is large, you can try using KLT or mean-shift. If the object is small, you can detect all moving objects using background subtraction, and track your object of interest using the Kalman Filter.